# Simplify sum of rational functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We obtained this expression for which we are quite certain it simplifies. Wolfram tools don't accept this 4 term expression.

$$    \frac{a(2ab+b^2)}{(a^2-b^2)(a^2-j^2)(a^2-r^2)} -  \frac{b(2ab+a^2)}{(a^2-b^2)(b^2-j^2)(b^2-r^2)}$$
 $$ +   \frac{j(j^2-(a+b)^2)}{(a^2-j^2)(j^2-b^2)(j^2-r^2)} +   \frac{r(r^2-(a+b)^2)}{(a^2-r^2)(r^2-b^2)(r^2-j^2)} $$

```
a*(2*a*b+b^2)/((a^2-b^2)*(a^2-j^2)*(a^2-r^2))
-b*(2*a*b+a^2)/((a^2-b^2)*(b^2-j^2)*(b^2-r^2))
+j*(j^2-(a+b)^2)/((a^2-j^2)*(j^2-b^2)*(j^2-r^2))
+r*(r^2-(a+b)^2)/((a^2-r^2)*(r^2-b^2)*(r^2-j^2))
```

The simpler model yields expression
$$    -\frac{e}{(e^2-j^2)(e^2-r^2)} + \frac{j}{(e^2-j^2)(j^2-r^2)} + \frac{r}{(e^2-r^2)(r^2-j^2)} $$
which simplifies to
$$  \frac{1}{(j+e)(r+e)(j+r)}  $$
which has good physical meaning. We hope to find analogous simplification, would you have comments how to proceed?

Comment: I used *Mathematica* and I got $$\frac{a^3+a^2 (3 b+j+r)+a r (3 b+j)+3 a b (b+j)+b (b+j) (b+r)}{(a+b) (a+j) (a+r) (b+j) (b+r) (j+r)}$$
(a^3+3 a b (b+j)+a (3 b+j) r+b (b+j) (b+r)+a^2 (3 b+j+r))/((a+b) (a+j) (b+j) (a+r) (b+r) (j+r))............Hope can be useful

Comment: *Wolfram* free won't accept this because it's too long
a*(2*a*b + b^2)/((a^2 - b^2)*(a^2 - j^2)*(a^2 - r^2)) - 
 b*(2*a*b + a^2)/((a^2 - b^2)*(b^2 - j^2)*(b^2 - r^2)) + 
 j*(j^2 - (a + b)^2)/((a^2 - j^2)*(j^2 - b^2)*(j^2 - r^2)) + 
 r*(r^2 - (a + b)^2)/((a^2 - r^2)*(r^2 - b^2)*(r^2 - j^2))

Comment: If this helps, the numerator can also be written in the form $(a+b) (a+b+j) (a+b+r)+a b (j+r)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used Maple and i got for the first four terms
$${\frac {{a}^{3}+3\,{a}^{2}b+{a}^{2}j+{a}^{2}r+3\,a{b}^{2}+3\,abj+3\,ab
r+ajr+{b}^{3}+{b}^{2}j+{b}^{2}r+bjr}{ \left( j+r \right)  \left( a+b
 \right)  \left( a+j \right)  \left( a+r \right)  \left( b+j \right) 
 \left( b+r \right) }}
$$

Comment: Many thanks Raffaele and Mr Graubner, very kind regards.